# Update one row's column based on other rows, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe like below:

```
Time   col1  col2  col3 
2      a     x     10
3      b     y     11
1      a     x     10
6      c     z     12
20     c     x     13
23     a     y     24
14     c     x     13     
16     b     y     11
...
```

and want to add a column to every row of dataframe based on other rows of dataframe, this is out dataframe:

```
Time   col1  col2  col3 cumVal
2      a     x     10   2
3      b     y     11   1
1      a     x     10   2
6      c     z     12   1
20     c     x     13   2
23     a     y     24   1
14     c     x     13   2
16     b     y     11   1
...
```

i have a try :

```
df['cumVal'] = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   min1 = row['Time']-10
   max1 = row['Time']+10
   ndf = df[(df.col1 == row.col1)&(df.col2 == row.col2)& (df.col3 == 
   row.col3)]
   df.iloc[index]['cumVal'] = len(ndf.query('@min1 <= Time <= @max1'))
```

but it is very slow, anybody could change my code to get more faster?

Comment: Its inefficient to iterate through rows like this, there may be some useful suggestions in the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)

Comment: Pretty much just drop the loop. The whole point of numpy, and by some extension pandas, is that you can use arrays in a way similar to scalars and get vectorized calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` on 'col1', 'col2' and 'col3' and in the [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) per group, use [`np.subtract`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html) as a ufunc of [`outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) to calculate all the differences between values in the column 'Time' of this group, then with `np.abs` inferior to 10 and `np.sum` on axis=0, you can calculate how many values are within +/- 10 for each value.

```
import numpy as np
df['cumVal'] = (df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'])['Time']
                  .transform(lambda x: (np.abs(np.subtract.outer(x, x))<=10).sum(0)))
print (df)
   Time col1 col2  col3  cumVal
0   2.0    a    x  10.0     2.0
1   3.0    b    y  11.0     1.0
2   1.0    a    x  10.0     2.0
3   6.0    c    z  12.0     1.0
4  20.0    c    x  13.0     2.0
5  23.0    a    y  24.0     1.0
6  14.0    c    x  13.0     2.0
7  16.0    b    y  11.0     1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It should give better performance:

```
df['cumVal'] = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   min1 = row['Time']-10
   max1 = row['Time']+10
   ndf = df[(df.Time>min1)&(df.Time<max1)&(df.col1 == row.col1)&(df.col2 == row.col2)& (df.col3 == 
   row.col3)]
   df.iloc[index]['cumVal'] = len(ndf)
```